# How to store or capture variable from one directory to another and execute with cut command in Linux

Tags: shell, variables, grep

I need to do as following, firstly I can read a server name from the text file line by line and do a grep command on it. The main task is to find the whole FQDN server name using only the hostname in the NB logs path and do other commands further. Here is the script I wrote but I am beginner in shell scripting and need your help. What do I missing here because I was thinking How to save a variable's value into another directory path and use it there? If I manually run these commands in command line it can give me what I do need it., thank you all..

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "Looking for the whole backup client names?"
for server in `cat ./List_ServerNames.txt`;
do
        cd /usr/openv/netbackup/logs/nbproxy/
        return_fqdn=`grep -im1 '$server' "$(ls -Art /usr/openv/netbackup/logs/nbproxy/ | tail -n1 | cut - 
        d : -f8)" | cut -d " " -f 6 | cut -c -36 | cut -d "(" -f 1`
        echo $return_fqdn
done
```

The output of script is down below:

Looking for the whole backup client names?

Comment: Don't use `'$server'`, but `"$server"` instead.  Copy/paste any example output you want to appear in your question and then put 4 spaces at the front of the line so it will display with the correct formatting. AND of course, `for` loops are likely to break. Search here for `[bash] while read done < file` and use the preferred solution for processing a file. Good luck.

Comment: Mat, it worked fine and got me what I need it, then I go for [bash] while read done < file to process with another my needs, thank you a lot and appreciate your hints. God bless you!